# Change alignment of text and image so the visual center is aligned properly. (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
text goes here
    
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--//col-->
    
        <div class='col-md- col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <div class='text-center'>
image goes here
    
    
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Pictures will tell what I'm trying to do better. Here is what it looks like right now:
bad-pupper.png
[image]

It's lined up properly but it doesnt look good. I want to match the center of the image to the text instead.
good-pupper.png
[image]

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the two content divs inside a new div. The new div you'll give a height, line-height. That way you can use vertical-align which will center the image the way you wanted

Answer (score 0):

just add `padding-top:somepixel` to your `text div`

like below

```
.text-center {
   padding-top:15px;
 }
```

Comment: that would just move it down further.

Comment: yeah my bad, I misunderstood.

Comment: the thing is, I actually solved it before asking the question using `top`. I was just thinking there had to be some bootstrap way of doing this since it must be so common.

Comment: there is nothing...like this

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do that,

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ryg2wtog/1/)

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="display:table;">
            <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
                <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                    <p>This is heading</p>
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Respective CSS**

```
p,img {
  margin:20px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

For your reference : [**Checkout this link**](http://howtocenterincss.com/)